# Why are the verbs connected with てhere? 連れて帰って

Tags: て-form

I understand that you need to use て to connect two verbs but all the example I have seen are like 起きて、コーヒーを飲んだ . There's always a more "complete" sentence for the action that follows the first verb. Is this sentence, あぁ連れて帰って
くれたんだね, just omitting the subject (you) and saying "Thank you for taking **and** bringing her home."? Of course the second verb is in て form as well do to ~てくれる conjugation.

Anyways, that is the only way I can interpret it. Whenever I try and find a similar sentence online by searching for "two verbs connected with て or something similar" I get sentences like this 起きて、コーヒーを飲んだ .

Comment: コーヒ > コーヒー; 飲みた > 飲んだ

Comment: What do you mean by `"complete" sentence`? What do you think is the difference between 起きて飲む and 連れて帰る? What makes 連れて帰る "incomplete"?

Comment: Maybe the point of @UCProgrammer was that it is not logical to split the 連れて帰って into separate actions like  連れる and 帰る but they only convey the [correct meaning] when used as a set, ie 連れ帰る works as [or maybe should be considered or maybe actually is] one single verb. If, so, one probably just needs to memorize these. I would say that 連れ[て]帰る is a really extreme example, and then there are the ones like 乗り遅れる which I guess would fall somewhere in between 起きて飲む and 連れ帰る.

Comment: @Tuomo you are correct.First, I understand that they are complete sentences but it just seems a bit odd to me mainly due to my lack of exposure to "short sentences" like that. I was looking at the english translation which was automatically provided for the sentence, "AH, YOU BROUGHT HER BACK FOR ME", and it added a bit to my confusion since the word "and" was never used. Had it been in the form, 連れ帰る, I would have probably understood it. Now I know that there are more ways of saying one thing though. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The verbs are connected in て-form is to emphasize that you do A first before you do B.

連れて帰る means to bring and go home.

Some other examples are:

- 聞いて来る: To ask and come (ask and return; go somewhere else to ask is implied)
- 食べて帰る: To eat and go home
- して見る: To do and see (basically means try)
- 連れて行く: To bring and go

The latter verb changes to Te-form too when you are asking someone else to do it or just the same as Te-form that you've been learning so far.